# PHP SOAP client send XML

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a web service with PHP. The following is my code -

Web Server -

```
require 'inventory_functions.php';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
$server = new SoapServer("inventory.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("getItemCount");
$server->handle();
```

Inventory_functions.php -

```
function getItemCount($upc){
    //in reality, this data would be coming from a database
    $items = array('12345'=>5,'19283'=>100,'23489'=>'234');
    return $items[$upc];
}
```

My Client Test -

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.xxx.co.uk/service/inventory.wsdl");
$return = $client->getItemName('12345');
print_r($return);
```

When I run this everythign is OK. the number "5" will output in my browser. WhatI really need is some help in how to go about sending data via XML to the SOAP server, from their I will add this data to MySQL.

How would I send the XML vie the client test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to know what XML input you should give your web-service in order to send for instance the value "5"?

In order to do that you should first analyse the wsdl file that is generated, then, depending on your programming language of choice for the client, you may generate a client Stub to interact with the Web-Service itself.

Alternatively, you may issue an HTTP POST with the XML directly to the web-service (should look something like this):

```
POST /service/mywebservice.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xxx.co.uk
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "<your.webservice.namespace>/getItemCount"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getItemCount xmlns="<your.webservice.namespace>">
      <value>5</value>
    </getItemCount>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I now understand that what you really want is to Send XML to the Web-Service. In order to do that can't you simply change the getItemCount PHP function in order to receive a String as an input? If you do that, the client may then send the XML as a string to the function getItemCount. In order to avoid messiness while embvedding XML string into a Soap request you might convert the original XML to a base64 string before sending it.